# How to do manual git clone in Jenkins over SSH

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh

In most cases I use the `git plugin` I choose the credential (username - private key) and I use `ssh://git@server.com:7999/project/repo.git` as URL. This works fine. A clone is possible.

Now I try to do the same with the `ssh-agent plugin` and not the `git-plugin`.

I use the SSH-agent plugin and select the credential (like with the git plugin).
than I choose to execute a shell:

```
git version;
git clone ssh://git@server.com:7999/project/repo.git
```

This does not work. What am I doing wrong?

```
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Answer (score 0):

This means that host key of the remote host was changed. (Prevention of man in the middle attacks)

Edit file manually:

```
~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Or use command:

```
ssh-keygen -R hostname
```

Also try this. Add your host to know hosts:

```
ssh-keyscan -t rsa YOUR_HOST.DOMAIN >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Comment: Executed all the steps, removed old one, added new one but still the same issue.

Comment: Please add that flag:
ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no
To your ssh commands:
For example:
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no"